# How to transfer data from spreadsheet into shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, data, united-kingdom

I am looking at Deprivation in the UK and there is some good data in the form of spreadsheets on this website http://www.communities.gov.uk/publications/corporate/statistics/indices2010

I would like to know how i can transfer some of the data into a shapefile??

Answer (score 12):

If there is no spatial data associated with it, you'll need to have some kind of geographical data to 'bind' it to.  The LSOA data column, in some of that data, links it to an object in the local authority, which suggests to me you'll struggle to do this, without the 'linked' spatial data inferred.

The data you need is LSOA data:

> Lower Layer Super Output Area - (LSOA) 
>   These have a minimum population of 1,000, with an overall mean of 1,500. They are built from groups of Output Areas. There are around 34,000 LSOAs in England and Wales.

I'd go back to that site and try and get hold if it, as once you have this LSOA data, you cna bind your statistical data to it.

**For completeness**

Please see [this](http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/images/CaseStudies_Geography_tcm97-51119.pdf) study

There are four geographies that will be discussed in this study. The bottom three are part of the statistical hierarchy:

- Local Authority - LA,
- Middle Layer Super Output Area - MSOA,
- Lower Layer Super Output Area - LSOA,
- Output Area - OA.

> Local authority - LA 
>   Local authority is a generic term for any level of local government in the UK. LAs include non-metropolitan districts, metropolitan districts, unitary authorities and London boroughs (in England); Welsh unitary authorities; Scottish council areas; and Northern Irish district council areas.
>
> Middle Layer Super Output Area - (MSOA) 
>   These areas have a minimum population of 5,000, with an overall mean of 7,200. They were built from groups of Lower Layer Super Output Areas and constrained by the local authority boundaries of 2003. There are around 7,000 MSOAs in England and Wales.
>
> Lower Layer Super Output Area - (LSOA) 
>   These have a minimum population of 1,000, with an overall mean of 1,500. They are built from groups of Output Areas. There are around 34,000 LSOAs in England and Wales.
>
> Output Area - (OA) 
>   In England and Wales OAs were designed from the 2001 Census. Postcodes were grouped into OAs according to a set of design criteria. OAs have a minimum population size of 100 with an overall mean of 300. There are around 175,000 OAs in England and Wales.

Comment: Which "study" are you quoting, Hairy?  Please credit your references when you copy and paste.

Comment: @whuber added - You can add some marks if you like ;)

Answer (score 6):

IF you have lat,lon, or xy coords in the spreadsheet you can create points from the spreadsheet.
Add the table to arcmap > Right click on the spreadsheet and select display xy data.
If you need these atached to polygons and if there is only one point per polygon, you can right click the polygon and select joins and relates > join.
Then in the what do you want to join select based on spatial location.
Finish the appropriate selections at the bottom and ok.

If none of the above works then you may have addresses in your spreadsheet.
You will have to geocode your addresses (to get them into points and then follow the rest.

If you don't have addresses you may have zip codes.
You can geocode to zip also, then spatial join the points to the zip boundaries.

If none of this works.
You will need to paste a small amount of data into your question for others to see and evaluate.
HTH

Comment: @Dpc1989 You need the LSOA areas - see below...

Answer (score 1):

The boundary data you'll need is available on CDs from the Office of National Statistics, order form available here;

http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/dissemination/Info.do?page=aboutneighbourhood/geography/superoutputareas/soaboundaries/soa-boundaries.htm