# How to join data in a spreadsheet to a shapefile ?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i transfer data from a spreadsheet into a shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12242/how-can-i-transfer-data-from-a-spreadsheet-into-a-shapefile)

I have data for Indices of Multiple Deprivation for the UK from this website: http://www.communities.gov.uk/publications/corporate/statistics/indices2010

The data in the spreadsheet is represented by Lower Layer Super Output Areas (LSOA) so I have managed to get a shapefile for the LSOA's in the UK and I want to bind the data from the spreadsheet into a shapefile that maps out the indices of multiple deprivation... How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Is this linked to:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12242/how-can-i-transfer-data-from-a-spreadsheet-into-a-shapefile/12248#12248

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a common column identifying your polygons/areas (or any other geometry type), the you can just do a [table join](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31793).  If you don't know how to do this, go to help in your ArcMap, type in Table Join in the search field, and do a read-up there.

Cheers

**EDIT**:
If you open your attribute table, then right mouse on the relevant column you'll be using for the table join and select "properties", you can see the "type" listed (in this case it's "double" --- see printscreen).  Match up to this in Access DBase.  I suspect this may be the root of your issue, as I've had this problem before.

[image]

Comment: I have tried that, It has matched the LSOA codes in the spreadsheets but hasnt joined any of the other fields i wish to import]

Comment: Quote from the link I sent you: "Rule #1. The fields being used in the Join from the spreadsheet and the feature class must be of the same Type, such as Double, Text, Short, and Integer." Could this be your issue? The data are served in an Excel spreadsheet, but may have been generated in another platform originally. Having said that, the "type" could be a mismatch on your variables. Open it in Access DataBase, and check the "type" of your column header. You might also try selecting "everything" in your Excel sheet, right mouse, and then set the formatting to "general".

Comment: You will need to match up to the "type" on the column in ArcMap too. See my edit above. I have added an a printscreen/explaination

Comment: and make sure there are no space or scecial chars in the column names in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Good point Brad!!  If there are spaces anywhere, fill them with an "underscore"

Comment: So i need to make sure the LSOA codes in the spreadsheet are the same "type" as those in the shapefile? how about all the other fields i want to join?

Comment: I have imported the data into a database and had a look at the data "type" drop down menu but there isnt a "string" type which is the type of the LSOA codes in ArcMap when i had a look at the properties?