# Adding information from excel into ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, database, excel

I am working in ArcGIS and have a excel sheet with data pertaining to properties.  I want to add this data to a map in ArcGIS of which i have property boundaries as a shapefile?

I have a common folio number between the two datasets.  However I am a novice and all answers have been over my head.  Please point me to a step by step process to inserting databases.

Comment: We need more info.  Are you saying you already have a shapefile with property boundaries and you want to join your Excel table to the already existing layer?  Or are you wanting to build a layer based off the Excel table?  If it's the former, you need a column in both the shapefile and Excel table that are keyed to each other so that they can be joined together.  If it's the latter, you will probably want coordinate info in your Excel table.

Comment: You would need to give a fair bit more information about what you've already tried and why it didn't work for anyone to really be able to give you a good answer.  From my understanding of the question, it should be, as described in help documents and forums all over the web (ex: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31793), bring the excel table into arcmap and do a standard table join joining it to the shapefile's attribute table based on a common key field.

Comment: To be honest I would like instructions on both.  Currently I am working on the former but I am having trouble with excel and i was informed that access works better but I dont know how to bring in a database file.

Comment: Also, the answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13238/22780 (and some other answers to that same question) have other links and resources related to working with excel data in ArcGIS.

Comment: please tell us what you are using to link the two datasets. do you have a unique id (numeric) a place name (text), or are you trying to manually link the two? BTW plese don't continue commenting. EDIT your original question with more information select the edit button...

Comment: You said (in response I think to @Baltok's two suggestions about what you may be asking) "To be honest I would like instructions on both" which says to me that you have at least two questions.  I think you should use the edit button to revise this question to focus it on whichever of these is more important to have answered first.  Any other question(s) can then be researched/asked separately.